# how to remove invalid object names on linkserver query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a linked server between 2 SQL Servers, and successfully made the linked server and I can query on the other server in linked server

But when I have a query, there appears a red line under the query which says "invalid object name", but I can query on it

Like this : linked server name: `REMOTERT`

```
SELECT done_buy, done_sell
FROM [REMOTERT].front.dbo.custbal
```

--> shows a red line and when I point mouse on it show invalid object name [REMOTERT].front.dbo.custbal. but if I press F5(Execute) can show the result

Comment: Have you tried `Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache` in your SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your cached memory is not refresh,

simply close sqlserver and open again. It will not come again.

Answer (score 0):

once you create a new SQL Server object, your newly created object does not get updated in the IntelliSence Local Cache and due to this, it shows red line underneath that object. So you just need to refresh SSMS IntelliSence Local Cache and once you refresh it, IntelliSence will automatically add newly created object in the cache and the red line will disappear. try this

```
Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache
```

or simply do

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

[image]